# Unit Test for Bank class in C#

Tags: c#

I'm learning to create unit tests for project written in C#. I've been follow the example on the MSDN website and now I just got stuck at how create a unit test when the amount is less than zero. The unit test is supposed to be failed when I run it. However, the way that I've written below, it passed :(
Would someone please let me know what I need to do to fix it ? Thanks

Here is what I have so far:

```
        // unit test method
        [TestMethod]
        [ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentOutOfRangeException))]
        public void Debit_WhenAmountIsLessThanZero_ShouldThrowArgumentOutOfRange()
        {
            // arrange
            double beginningBalance = 11.99;
            double debitAmount = -100.00;


            BankAccount account = new BankAccount("Mr. Bryan Walton", beginningBalance);

            // act
            account.Debit(debitAmount);

            // Not sure about this one
            // on my main program, I use if...else to handle
            // the situation when amount > balance by throwing the exception
            double actual = account.Balance;
            Assert.IsTrue(actual < 0, "Actual balance is greater than 0");            
        }
```

This is the method that I'm testing on

```
        public void Debit(double amount)
        {
            if (m_frozen)
            {
                throw new Exception("Account frozen");
            }

            if (amount > m_balance)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("amount");
            }

            if (amount < 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("amount");
            }

            m_balance -= amount;
        }
```

Comment: You should add the code for the BankAccount class as well.

Comment: If BankAccount#Debit throws an exception, the Assert code will never be reached, thus your test will be successful as you expect an Exception

Comment: `Assert.IsTrue(actual < 0, "Actual balance is greater than 0"); ` is backwards. You are asserting that it's true that the actual amount is **less than** zero.

Comment: As AD.Net says, your test is working properly and the Assert is unnecessary

Comment: @JleruOHeP: I'm pretty new to C# and all the unit tests, so I did not know there's another `assert` method to check. Most of the tutorials that I've looked up on the Internet, they're using `Assert.AreEqual`. Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: @HoangMinh I`ve added my variant as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The test looks just fine, you expect an exception when amount is negative and it's throwing exception, otherwise it won't pass. Although in this kind of tests, I usually have something like this at the end.

```
Assert.Fail("Should have thrown exception because of ........")
```

That `Assert` will fail the test in case the exception is not thrown when expected.

Comment: I think now I understand the way it works. Thank you for your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

you could do this:

```
Assert.AreEqual( beginningBalance - debitAmount, account.Balance );
```

to verify the value is what you expect, instead of just less than zero.

Answer (score 1):

As a personal preference, I like when all my tests are successful :) So I would write something like this:

```
var exception = Assert.Throws<ArgumentOutOfRangeException>(() => account.Debit(debitAmount));
Assert.That(exception.ParamName, Is.Equal("amount"));
```

And, possibly, throw different types of exceptions and message for them.